# Silverlight and Non-Public members

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-5.0, silverlight-2.0

Is it possible somehow to access non-public properties in Silverlight? Maybe using reflection?

I've tried following steps:

1. Get class type
2. Get property info by prop name
3. prop.GetValue(obj, null)

It says: MethodAccessException... A there any ways to workaround/(go another way) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Officially, you will need to run the browser in elevated permissions in order to access private/protected members. With normal privileges reflection will only get you access to the members in the same assembly.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stfy7tfc(v=vs.95).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stfy7tfc%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)